# How arrange diagram in R

Tags: r, igraph

I want to get diagram similar to picture below, but code I use creates different diagram. With `rbind` I added some hierarchy to a diagram. In data frame `col0` there is a string with names of animals. In `col1` string is split into individual animals & `col2` is adding latin name for a animal. `col1` data are always changing and in `col2` data constant (there always be feline or canis names in that column).

```
library(igraph)
# I create my dataframe with animals
df <- data.frame(col0 = c("Cat Dog Wolf", "Cat Dog Wolf", "Cat Dog Wolf"),
col1 = c( "Cat", "Dog", "Wolf"),
col2 = c( "Feline", "Canis", "Canis2"))
# Add extra lines for hierarchy 
# These lines work with current graph for a new one these should be replace or deleted
df <-rbind(df, data.frame(col0 = "Cat Dog Wolf", col1 = "Feline", col2 ="Animal"))
df <-rbind(df, data.frame(col0 = "Cat Dog Wolf", col1 = "Canis", col2 = "Animal"))
df <-rbind(df, data.frame(col0 = "Cat Dog Wolf", col1 = "Canis2", col2 = "Canis"))

##########
df <-df[c('col2', 'col1')]
names(df) <-c('from', 'to')
abc <-union(df$to, df$from)
###########

g <-graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = abc)
plot(g, vertex.size = 20, vertex.label.dist = 0.5, vertex.color = c("blue", 
"red", "green", "white", "orange"  ),
edge.arrow.size = 0.5, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g))
```

This is the graph that the above code outputs, but it's not quite what I want:

[image]

I want a similar diagram to what's shown below:

[image]

Comment: Change your dataframe I guess. I would not represent this datafrmae like what you want. There's no link between canis dog and canis2 wolf in the data.

Comment: I think that you are asking that every leaf of the tree should be eliminated and its name should be combined with its parent. What is a node had two children that are leaves?

Comment: Well you can change `rbind` whatever you feel like. to add all necessary hierarchy

Comment: In worst case scenario you can just drop latin names from diagram and do without them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I understand what you want, but I will restate the problem
so that you can confirm whether or not I understood.  I think that what
you want to do is this:

Find all of the leaves in the tree, i.e. the nodes with no descendants. 
Each leaf will have one parent.  Rename the parent with the name of the 
leaf, then delete the leaf from the graph. The following code implements that.

```
## Assume that we have created the graph g using your code
g2 = g           # Keep original graph intact
SourceNodes = sapply(strsplit(attr(E(g2), "vnames"), "\\|"), "[", 1)
DestNodes = sapply(strsplit(attr(E(g2), "vnames"), "\\|"), "[", 2)

## Leaf nodes are nodes that are destinations, but not sources
## Also need the node numbers for later deletion
(LeafNodes = DestNodes[which(!(DestNodes%in% SourceNodes ))])
[1] "Cat"  "Dog"  "Wolf"
(LeafNumbers = match(LeafNodes, attr(V(g), "name")))
[1] 1 2 3

## Find the parents of the leaves
(UpOne = SourceNodes[match(LeafNodes, DestNodes)])
[1] "Feline" "Canis"  "Canis2"

## Rename the UpOne nodes (parents of leaves)
vertex_attr(g2)$name[match(UpOne, vertex_attr(g2)$name)] = LeafNodes

## Now delete the leaf nodes and plot
g2 = delete_vertices(g2, LeafNumbers)
plot(g2, vertex.size = 20, vertex.label.dist = 0.5, 
    vertex.color = c("red", "green", "white", "orange"  ),
    edge.arrow.size = 0.5, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g2))
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I know maybe it's too late to ask, but how would you handle if there is more than on wolf? and they need to go in one line down from a dog

Comment: Do you mean that there are Canis2->Wolf1 and  Canis3->Wolf2  below Canis?

Comment: that looks like the desired results.  What would the input be?

Comment: I asked a new quastion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802712/how-to-arrange-nodes-in-r

Comment: Thanks.  I will respond there.