# How to arrange nodes in R

Tags: r, igraph

In data frame there are animals, `Cat` and `Dog` always goes first and the rest of animals goes below dog like in final picture.

```
`library(igraph)
 # I create my dataframe with animals
df <- data.frame(col0 = c("Dog Cat Wolf Wolf1", "Dog Cat Wolf Wolf1", "Dog 
Cat Wolf Wolf1", "Dog Cat Wolf Wolf1"),
col1 = c( "Dog", "Cat", "Wolf", "Wolf1"),
col2 = c( "Canis", "Feline", "Canis2", "Canis3"))
# Add extra lines for hierarchy 
df <-rbind(df, data.frame(col0 = "Cat Dog Wolf", col1 = "Feline", col2="Animal"))
df <-rbind(df, data.frame(col0 = "Cat Dog Wolf", col1 = "Canis", col2 = "Animal"))
df <-rbind(df, data.frame(col0 = "Cat Dog Wolf", col1 = "Canis2", col2 ="Canis"))
df <-rbind(df, data.frame(col0 = "Cat Dog Wolf", col1 = "Canis3", col2 ="Canis2"))

 df <-df[c('col2', 'col1')]
 names(df) <-c('from', 'to')
 abc <-union(df$to, df$from)

 g <-graph.data.frame(df, directed = TRUE, vertices = abc)
 plot(g, vertex.size = 20, vertex.label.dist = 0.5, vertex.color = c("blue", 
 "red", "green", "white", "orange", "pink", "cyan"  ),
 edge.arrow.size = 0.5, layout = layout.reingold.tilford(g))`
```

After code is use I get this diagram:

[image]

When should look like this:

[image]

Comment: It's not duplicate different diagram, different data frame

Comment: Just because the data is different does not mean the question is different. To me it looks like you want to merge the leaf nodes into their parents. Which was answered in your previous question, albeit with **slightly** different data.

Comment: Please clarify what the exact relation with your other question is: to be very clear: the question @emilliman5 refers to.

Comment: @DeividasKiznis   - I think that this _is_ a duplicate.  If you run exactly the same code as in my previous solution on your new data, it will produce the output you are requesting.